# Using Cookiecutter Django Docker backup functions on a Windows machine

Tags: django, windows, docker, cookiecutter-django

I have used Cookiecutter Django to create a dockerized project, which I have deployed to production.

I can use the commands for backing up, checking backups, and restoring all fine on my production server, which is a linux machine.

I was hoping to move the backup from my production environment to my development environment, which is a windows machine, however using the commands throws an issue "/usr/bin/env: ‘bash\r’: No such file or directory".  I've searched around and seen this is a windows files encoding issue but can't find an answer which works for me for resolving that issue.

Has anyone faced this issue before and found a workaround?

Thanks for any help anyone can offer!